# Raise ValueError("Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values") ValueError: Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values

Tags: python, matplotlib, openpyxl

I am making a simple Python program for task management and financial reporting. The error that I am receiving is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evangertis/development/PythonAutomation/IGTS/Budgeting/financial_progress_report.py", line 57, in <module>
    plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct="%1.1f%%")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2772, in pie
    return gca().pie(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1442, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3196, in pie
    raise ValueError("Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values")
ValueError: Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values
```

and the program is

```
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Prompt the user to answer the morning checklist questions
priority1 = input("What is your top priority for the day? ")
priority2 = input("What is your second priority for the day? ")
priority3 = input("What is your third priority for the day? ")
advice = input("Who can you call for advice on achieving your goals? ")
actions = input("What specific actions do you need to take to move closer to your objectives? ")
devotional = input("Did you take 10-15 minutes for morning devotional or meditation? ")
workout = input("Did you complete a 30-45 minute workout or core exercise routine? ")
budget_review = input("Did you review your budget and expenses for the day? ")
money_made_today = input("How much money did you make today? ")
money_spent_today = input("How much money did you spend today? ")
weekly_expenses = input("How much money do you need to live for this week? ")
last_week_expenses = input("How much money did you need to live for last week? ")
money_made_this_week = input("How much money did you make this week? ")
money_made_last_week = input("How much money did you make last week? ")
projected_monthly_income = input("How much money will you make by the end of the month? ")
last_month_income = input("How much money did you make last month? ")
tax_allocation = input("How much money needs to be allocated for taxes? ")
gratitude = input("Did you write down three things you are grateful for today? ")
adjustments = input("What adjustments do you need to make to reach your financial and exercise goals for the week? ")
affirmation = input("What positive affirmation or quote inspires you to be productive and focused? ")

# Save the responses in an Excel file
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
sheet.title = "Morning Checklist"
sheet["A1"] = "Priority 1"
sheet["B1"] = "Priority 2"
sheet["C1"] = "Priority 3"
sheet["D1"] = "Advice"
sheet["E1"] = "Actions"
sheet["F1"] = "Devotional"
sheet["G1"] = "Workout"
sheet["H1"] = "Budget Review"
sheet["I1"] = "Money Made Today"
sheet["J1"] = "Money Spent Today"
sheet["K1"] = "Weekly Expenses"
sheet["L1"] = "Last Week Expenses"
sheet["M1"] = "Money Made This Week"
sheet["N1"] = "Money Made Last Week"
sheet["O1"] = "Projected Monthly Income"
sheet["P1"] = "Last Month Income"
sheet["Q1"] = "Tax Allocation"
sheet["R1"] = "Gratitude"
sheet["S1"] = "Adjustments"
sheet["T1"] = "Affirmation"
sheet.append([priority1, priority2, priority3, advice, actions, devotional, workout, budget_review, money_made_today, money_spent_today, weekly_expenses, last_week_expenses, money_made_this_week, money_made_last_week, projected_monthly_income, last_month_income, tax_allocation, gratitude, adjustments, affirmation])
workbook.save("morning_checklist.xlsx")

# Display a visualization of the financial data
labels = ["Money Made Today", "Money Spent Today", "Weekly Expenses", "Last Week Expenses", "Money Made This Week", "Money Made Last Week", "Projected Monthly Income", "Last Month Income", "Tax Allocation"]
values = [float(money_made_today), -float(money_spent_today), -float(weekly_expenses), -float(last_week_expenses), float(money_made_this_week), float(money_made_last_week), float(projected_monthly_income), float(last_month_income), -float(tax_allocation)]  

plt.bar(x=range(len(values)),height=values)
plt.title("Financial Overview")
plt.show()
```

Input:

```
What is your top priority for the day? create a contact list for marketing campaign 
What is your second priority for the day? update marketing strategy
What is your third priority for the day? call mentor for advice and update a marketing strategy
Who can you call for advice on achieving your goals? X
What specific actions do you need to take to move closer to your objectives? create contact list
Did you take 10-15 minutes for morning devotional or meditation? yes
Did you complete a 30-45 minute workout or core exercise routine? yes
Did you review your budget and expenses for the day? yes
How much money did you make today? 0
How much money did you spend today? 0
How much money do you need to live for this week? 1174
How much money did you need to live for last week? 439
How much money did you make this week? 17.89
How much money did you make last week? 3.50
How much money will you make by the end of the month? 3522
How much money did you make last month? 89.50
How much money needs to be allocated for taxes? 300
Did you write down three things you are grateful for today? yes
What adjustments do you need to make to reach your financial and exercise goals for the week? call certifified financial planner (CFP) and my friend who is a personal trainer then collect their advice and update my budget and exercise routine
What positive affirmation or quote inspires you to be productive and focused? you are wonderfully and fearfully made
```

Expected output:

1. An Excel sheet with the answers
2. A visualization showing the progress

### Update

I followed the advice from the answers below and I'm almost there. [image]

I would like to get this to show how to correlate the priorities to the money generated/lost. Is this possible?

Comment: A comment from the OP under an answer says that the answer "didn't work", but no further details are given. For now I will cast an on-hold vote requesting a [mcve] - we can reopen if an update is made.

Answer (score 1):

This one's a little tricky - the following is valid:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.pie([1,2,3], labels=['a','b','c'], autopct="%1.1f%%")
plt.title("Financial Overview")
plt.show()
```

But the following is not and will yield the error you're seeing:

```
plt.pie([1,-2,3], labels=['a','b','c'], autopct="%1.1f%%")
plt.title("Financial Overview")
plt.show()
```

You can't have negatives slices of a pie chart. The following works, but I'm not sure how to get it to display labels.

```
plt.bar(x=range(len(values)),height=values)
plt.title("Financial Overview")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice, thank you so much. I followed the program instructions and it brings me right back to you because this is my priority and I am working entirely alone right now. Do you know how to get the correlation between the priorities and the money spent/earned?

Comment: Try `plt.barh(y=labels,width=values)`

Comment: tried it and it didn't work

Comment: should, what are you getting

Comment: @EvanGertis: would you update your post with the specific problem you received in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing in negative values for x (the wedge sizes) here:

```
values = [float(money_made_today), -float(money_spent_today), -float(weekly_expenses), -float(last_week_expenses), float(money_made_this_week), float(money_made_last_week), float(projected_monthly_income), float(last_month_income), -float(tax_allocation)]  

plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct="%1.1f%%")
```

The error you're seeing explicitly says that these cannot be negative ("Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values"). I'd start there.

doc: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html

The error itself can be found here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3221